# A microservice architechtural interview task

Tags: rest, architecture, microservices

I am looking for a job as a system analyst and in interviews I come across tasks like this.
Imagine that you are working on a credit scoring system that decides whether a user is creditworthy. The user fills an application form and receives notification (say, in SMS) with the scoring result. Apart from the data provided by the user the system utilizes their credit bureau information.
What questions will you ask to clarify the task and what microservices will you propose to create for this system?
It is obvious that the solution I propose is too simple or not enough detailed, so I will be most grateful for the help.

I usually suggest that there will be 4 microsevices:

- Service requesting information about the user from the bank database;
- Service requesting credit bureau information;
- Service performing scoring;
- Service sending notifications.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some questions that come to mind about clarify the task. Would be...

1. What is the intended use of the credit scoring system? Is it intended to be used by a financial institution to decide whether to grant a loan, or is it intended for some other purpose?
2. Who will be responsible for maintaining and updating the system? Will there be a dedicated team of developers and analysts working on the system, or will it be the responsibility of a single individual or department?
3. What data sources will be used to generate the credit scores? Will the system rely solely on information from the user's credit bureau, or will it also incorporate data from other sources, such as bank account information or employment history?
4. How will the system handle users who do not have a credit bureau file? Will there be a process in place to handle these cases, or will the system simply reject these users?

Based on the information, I came up with the same microservices as you.

1. A user data service that stores and manages information about users, including their personal and financial information.
2. A credit scoring service that calculates credit scores based on the data provided by the user and other sources.
3. A notification service that sends SMS messages to users with their credit scores and any other relevant information.
4. A data integration service that manages the flow of data between the different microservices and external data sources.

This is just one possible solution, and the specific services involved would be dependent on finding out more information on the business requirements.